# Simple static web app fails to deploy to Azure due to internal server error

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-static-web-app

I'm trying to deploy an extremely simple static web app skeleton to Azure, but can't get it to work. I keep getting "InternalServerError" and the instruction to "please try again later", but as it's been more than 24 hours of trying and retrying, I doubt that this will get me anywhere.

Since the Microsoft Learn Q&A site, which is supposed to be the official community support section for Azure, keeps deleting my questions for "violating community guideline", I'm trying my luck here.

### Context

The app I'm trying to deploy is literally the most minimal of test apps. I have a repository hosted on Azure DevOps containing the default Angular app template from `ng new` as a frontend, and a default Azure Functions starter project generated through the Azure Functions extension in VS Code for the API project. There's not much more to this than having followed the basic first steps on getting an Angular app deployed as an Azure SWA.

### Local attempt

Crucially, I have tested all of this using the Azure Static Web App CLI, and it works locally, so there doesn't seem to be anything inherently wrong with the project itself. SWA CLI created the following `swa-cli.config.json` in my project's main directory:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://aka.ms/azure/static-web-apps-cli/schema",
  "configurations": {
    "test-app": {
      "appLocation": "source\\test-app",
      "apiLocation": "functions",
      "outputLocation": "dist\\test-app",
      "appBuildCommand": "npm run build",
      "apiBuildCommand": "dotnet publish -c Release",
      "run": "npm start",
      "appDevserverUrl": "http://localhost:4200"
    }
  }
}
```

When I run `swa start`, I can open `localhost:4280` in my browser and I get the Angular app, and when I open `localhost:7071/api/TestRequest` I get a response of `Welcome to Azure Functions!`. So both the frontend and the API project work.

However, I simply can't manage to deploy this same thing to Azure. Here's what I do:

### Azure Portal deployment attempt

1. In my Azure Portal, I choose *Create a resource* and select *Static Web App*
2. From the dropdowns, I choose my existing subscription and resource group, and give the app a name like *test*.
3. I choose the *Free* hosting plan and the *West Europe* region for Azure Functions, although I also tried other options here without success.
4. For *Source*, I choose *Azure DevOps*, and from the selection boxes below, select the appropriate *Organization*, *Project*, *Repostiory*, and *Branch*.
5. For *Build Preset*, I choose *Angular*, and use the same paths for *App location*, *API location*, and *Output location* as in the config file shown above.
6. When clicking *Review + create* and then *Create*, the first thing that will happen is that a new Personal Access Token is created in my Azure DevOps account, and a YAML file is committed to the given branch, looking like this:

```
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

pr:
branches:
  include:
    - deployment-test
trigger:
branches:
  include:
    - deployment-test

jobs:
- job: build_and_deploy_job
displayName: Build and Deploy Job
condition: or(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'),or(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'),eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI')))
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
variables:
- group: Azure-Static-Web-Apps-<redacted>-variable-group
steps:
- checkout: self
  submodules: true
- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  inputs:
    azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_<redacted>)
###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
# For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
    app_location: "/source/test-app" # App source code path
    api_location: "/functions" # Api source code path - optional
    output_location: "dist/test-app" # Built app content directory - optional
###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######
```

7. After being forwarded to the deployment overview, it takes only a few seconds for a red error bar to appear, saying "Deployment failed. Click here for details". These details shown are:

```
{
"code":"DeploymentFailed",
"message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.",
"details":[
  {
    "code":"InternalServerError",
    "message":"There was an unexpected InternalServerError.  Please try again later.  x-ms-correlation-request-id: 6e2ab150-1542-4756-bc65-19d207d7b4f7"
  }
]
}
```

8. Following the instructions to check the deployment operation details, I get the following further information:

```
[
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/<redacted>/resourceGroups/<redacted>/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/Microsoft.Web-StaticApp-Portal-48a26296-8238/operations/D5DB44C607F1BB9D",
  "operationId": "D5DB44C607F1BB9D",
  "properties": {
    "provisioningOperation": "Create",
    "provisioningState": "Failed",
    "timestamp": "2023-03-16T15:39:54.1309018Z",
    "duration": "PT4.4853634S",
    "trackingId": "66113984-7e07-4bf8-bcae-bdeb3024f87a",
    "statusCode": "BadRequest",
    "statusMessage": {
      "status": "Failed",
      "error": {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "There was an unexpected InternalServerError.  Please try again later.  x-ms-correlation-request-id: 6e2ab150-1542-4756-bc65-19d207d7b4f7"
      }
    },
    "targetResource": {
      "id": "/subscriptions/<redacted>/resourceGroups/<redacted>/providers/Microsoft.Web/staticSites/test",
      "resourceType": "Microsoft.Web/staticSites",
      "resourceName": "test"
    }
  }
}
]
```

### Update: Azure CLI deployment attempt

I managed to get more detailed information by trying the same deployment using the `az staticwebapp create` CLI with the `--debug` flag. Here is the crucial part I see in the log:

```
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: Request URL: 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<redacted>/resourceGroups/<redacted>/providers/Microsoft.Web/staticSites/test?api-version=2022-03-01'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: Request method: 'PUT'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: Request headers:
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Content-Length': '421'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Accept': 'application/json'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'x-ms-client-request-id': 'a6d7bd28-c417-11ed-af62-00155d86942d'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'CommandName': 'staticwebapp create'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'ParameterSetName': '-n -g --api-location --app-location -b -l --login-with-ado --output-location --sku -s --debug --verbose'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'User-Agent': 'AZURECLI/2.45.0 (MSI) azsdk-python-azure-mgmt-web/7.0.0 Python/3.10.8 (Windows-10-10.0.19042-SP0)'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Authorization': '*****'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: Request body:
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: {"location": "westeurope", "sku": {"name": "Free", "tier": "Free"}, "properties": {"repositoryUrl": "<redacted>", "branch": "deployment-test", "repositoryToken": "<redacted>", "buildProperties": {"appLocation": "source/test-app", "apiLocation": "functions", "appArtifactLocation": "dist/test-app"}}}
urllib3.connectionpool: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): management.azure.com:443
urllib3.connectionpool: https://management.azure.com:443 "PUT /subscriptions/<redacted>/resourceGroups/<redacted>/providers/Microsoft.Web/staticSites/test?api-version=2022-03-01 HTTP/1.1" 500 36
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: Response status: 500
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: Response headers:
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Pragma': 'no-cache'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Content-Length': '36'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Expires': '-1'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/10.0'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'X-AspNet-Version': '4.0.30319'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'x-ms-failure-cause': 'service'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-writes': '1199'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'x-ms-request-id': '2d9ae5aa-8800-48d1-90ab-bb96a32f85fa'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'x-ms-correlation-request-id': '2d9ae5aa-8800-48d1-90ab-bb96a32f85fa'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'x-ms-routing-request-id': 'SWITZERLANDNORTH:20230316T162905Z:2d9ae5aa-8800-48d1-90ab-bb96a32f85fa'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Date': 'Thu, 16 Mar 2023 16:29:05 GMT'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies:     'Connection': 'close'
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: Response content:
cli.azure.cli.core.sdk.policies: {"Message":"An error has occurred."}
```

So, basically, it looks like there's nothing I can do? I'm on the "free $150 a month" tier included with a Visual Studio Enterprise subscription, which does not entitle to technical support on Azure. Is Azure simply dead for me, then, with no recourse?

### How to proceed?

Unless Azure is broken completely, which I somehow doubt, I feel like there must be something I can change or firmly slap into place to get an SWA deployed. But I'm all out of ideas, and I don't feel like Azure is giving me enough information to know where to look next.

I'd be very grateful for any ideas on what I could try next! (Short of spending $29 for technical support on a test app).

Comment: Internal Server error is more generic error and can be caused by multiple reasons. Whenever you create static webapp (swa) tries to create a workflow.yaml file in the specific repo( either in azure devops/ in github). Here the deployment might be failed due to lack of write permissions on the main branch. Could you please verify the permission and retry the operation.

Comment: Thank you @VenkateshDodda for the suggestion! Write access to the repository should be fine. I'm using Azure and Azure DevOps on the same account, and when I attempt the deployment, I see that Azure creates a PAT in my DevOps account, and its permissions show "Code (Full)". Also, even though the deployment fails, the workflow YAML is actually successfully created and committed, I can see it in my repository afterwards.

Comment: Are you facing this issue if you are using GitHub as source control also or only with the Azuredevops source control ?

Comment: @VenkateshDodda Yes, as it turns out it works fine if I deploy from GitHub, so it's a problem only with DevOps. But as my workplace is all set up on DevOps, moving projects to GitHub is not really an option. Could the issue be related to the fact that my subscription is associated with my employer's Directory (through which I have the VS Enterprise subscription)? Could they have configured something that breaks DevOps integration? (That was the goal of this PoC on my personal $150 subscription: determine the general feasibility of this Azure Cloud integration with our DevOps.)